# Does Firebase use `WeakReference` for their listeners on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, listener, weak-references, weak

I want to know if Firebase uses the `WeakReference` class for references to listener instances.

Imagine the following scenario: A silly developer attaches a `ValueEventListener`in `onCreate()` of his `SillyActivity` and forgets to remove it. Does the listeners reference get invalid if the `SillyActivity` get's killed? Otherwise it would remain in the process heap and even keep being executed.

In other words: Being a `WeakReference`, it wouldn't be a disaster for the listener not to get removed if it's only added once in the lifecycle of an activity/fragment. It wouldn't leak over the lifetime of the activity/fragment.

Another related bonus question is, if listeners added with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` get removed automatically. The documentation claims to fire the listener once but not to remove it. I think it get's removed automatically - this would be the easiest way to achieve a one time fire.

Comment: WeakReferences should generally not be used in Android.  Dalvik will immediately clean up any object with only weak references to it.  As opposed to the JVM which will leave them around until it needs the resources, making it a viable cache candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it, otherwise it wouldn't work with things like this:

```
polls.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Since there wouldn't be any non-`WeakReference`s to the listener.

Comment: That makes sense. Then it really IS a desaster for the listener not getting removed.

Comment: Thinking about the bonus question, how else could it be implemented? Obviously the listener gets also removed automatically when added with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`.

Comment: Where do the docs claim to not remove it?  It probably just calls all the callbacks and then clears it list of them...

Comment: Oh, maybe I didn't express myself clearly enough. The docs do **not** claim to remove it.